# Max average series in ordered list

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the greatest average values for different duration in a list.

Let's say I have the following data:

```
var randomList = new List<int>();
var random = new Random(1969);

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    randomList.Add(random.Next(0, 500));
}
```

That produces the following list:

```
190
279
37
413
90
131
64
129
287
172
```

I'm trying to get the highest average values for the different sets 0-9.

Set 0 (one item in a row) = 413 (index 3)

Set 1 (two items in a row) = 252 (average index 3,4)

Set 9 (10 items in a row) = 179 (average of the entire list)

I've been beating my head on this a while. I'm trying to find an efficient way to write this so I have the least traversals as possible. In production, I'll have lists with 3500-6000 points.

How do I find the highest average values for the different sets 0-9?

Comment: How you are calculating the `highest average` for a set in general? is their any equation for that? And more over any effort from your side?

Comment: How did you work out 503 for 2 items in a row, when none of the numbers are larger than 413? (That's just the sum, not the average)

Comment: @un-lucky just Avg for the items in a series. so Avg(items:0,1,2) vs Avg(items:1,2,3) vs Avg(items:2,3,4) ect.  That's for three items in a row.

I've tried a ton, but it's dumb code and doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidG Ah, I was trying a sum technique before where I was trying to subtract a number from the sum at the beginning of the list then add the latest number and compare it to the previous sum.  When I wrote this out I forgot to divide that 503/2.  It's fixed now.

Comment: Interesting problem. Yet, I do not see a better way than brute force.

Comment: Which means Set 0 = `(190+279+37)/3`  but it is not  `413`

Comment: What you are going to do for last 10 element ? Pretty much you want an element to be return, average of element and next element near him and average of all for every item of the collection ?

Comment: @un-lucky Set 0 is the average of sequences of length = 1, hence it is 413

Comment: I love when they just ask something and go away ... Can you answer a question ?

Comment: @mybirthname Give OP a chance, he was answering earlier.

Comment: @DavidG so he wants to find the largest average of 2 near elements ?

Comment: @mybirthname Or 3, or 4, or 5 etc.

Comment: @mybirthname For the last element I would want the average for the entire list (since it would take into account all 10 elements).

Comment: @DavidG You're correct, largest average for near elements, but in this case it would be 1-9.  Another way to say it is "What's the highest average n contiguous numbers".  Where n would be 0 to list.Count-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't the most efficient way to do it, but it works fine:

Basically, we use a stack to track the items we've traversed. Then to calculate the average for `n` last items, we peek at `n` items from the stack.

```
void Main()
{
    var randomList = new List<int>();
    var random = new Random(1969);

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        randomList.Add(random.Next(0, 500));
    }

    // Use the values from the original post for validation
    randomList = new List<int> { 190, 279, 37, 413, 90, 131, 64, 129, 287, 172 };

    const int numSets = 9;
    var avgDict = Enumerable.Range(1, numSets).ToDictionary(e => e, e => (double)0);
    var s = new Stack<int>();
    foreach (var item in randomList)
    {
        s.Push(item);
        for (var i = 1; i <= numSets; i++)
        {
            if (s.Count >= i)
            {
                var avg = s.Take(i).Average();
                if (avg > avgDict[i])
                    avgDict[i] = avg;
            }
        }
    }
    avgDict.Dump();
}
```

Yields the result:

```
1 413 
2 251.5 
3 243 
4 229.75 
5 201.8 
6 190 
7 183.714285714286 
8 178.75 
9 180
```

I'm unsure as to the implications of using a `Stack` for large lists, when we only need 9-10 items. Might be a good case for a custom limited size stack

Comment: Did you intentionally set randomList to a new list twice... because it is completely overwriting that for loop that adds values to it...

Comment: Also a code dump helps nobody at all here. This question is off topc and should be closed.

Comment: @ChrisThompson Yes, it was intentional to reproduce the 'random' values as per the question to validate the output

Comment: @Rob the idea of using the stack is brilliant. I'm not sure if this can with stand the 6000 item list that the OP asked, but your way is great in traversing all the sums.

Comment: It's *too broad* because it's asking **us** to write their code for them, not asking for debugging help. Also, would you rather I vote to close and not stick around to help, because surely that's being spectacularly unhelpful?

Comment: @DVT I agree - I haven't personally tested the performance of a stack containing more 6000 items. I would assume it shouldn't be extremely slow, as we're still only peeking at the top `n` items (which should be cheap), though it doesn't sit well with me - and would ideally be implemented with a fixed-size stack

Comment: @Rob This looks great, stack is a brilliant idea. I'm going to play with it and see how fast I can get it.

Answer (score 1):

In your comment, you mentioned `Avg(items:0,1,2) vs Avg(items:1,2,3) vs Avg(items:2,3,4)`

Not sure if this is what you want but I came up with this.

First, get random number, then get average of 3 numbers. Then, get the largest average value.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var randomList = new List<int>();
        var random = new Random(1969);
        int TotalRandomNumber = 10; //Change this accordingly
        for (var i = 0; i < TotalRandomNumber ; i++)
        {
            randomList.Add(random.Next(0, 500));
        }

        foreach (var item in randomList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Random Number: " + item);
        }

        var AveNum = new List<double>();
        int range = 3; //Change this for different range
        for (int i = 1; i < TotalRandomNumber - range; i++)
        {
            var three = randomList.GetRange(i, range);
            double result = three.Average();
            Console.WriteLine("Average Number: " + result);
            AveNum.Add(result);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Largest: " + AveNum.Max());
    }
```